# SQLite Clearing Database Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I'm trying to update the data in my SQLite database on iPhone. I'd like to drop and recreate the table (it's not big), or just truncate it, but I can't seem to do that.

Running

```
char *errorMsg;
    NSString *truncSQL = @"TRUNCATE TABLE GAMES;";
    if (sqlite3_exec(database, [truncSQL UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errorMsg) != SQLITE_OK){
        NSLog(@"Error: %s", errorMsg);
        NSLog(truncSQL);
    }
```

gives me a database is locked error. There shouldn't be any active reads or anything from the database. How do I get it to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops, that was stupid.

Figured it out!

Accidentally missed a sqlite3_finalize(); statement somewhere!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes older versions of SQLite will give a "database locked" error if the file `[DATABASE].journal` exists. If you are *sure* nothing is accessing the database, try deleting that file.